# How do multiple contributors work on Wordpress.org (i.e. does each have to download the software)?

Tags: wordpress, admin

More context: our work project is setting up a blog in which numerous contributors (25+) worldwide will be posting content. All resources suggest Wordpress.org over Wordpress.com. 

Before we set this up, can anyone let me know how admin, editing, or contributor roles work with the software? Specifically, can people assigned to various roles contribute without accessing the site via the software, or does each contributor need to download it to have access?

I hope to learn more information prior to setting up this shared blog, which is why I have a blind eye to how this works. Without easy sharing access, I might suggest using Wordpress.com since it is managed in-browser.

Answer (score 0):

wordpress is a cms for blogging with a lot of plugins and it`s best for your job that you describe. you can read more about role and capabilities in this page.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities